# How to revert a git rm -r .?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash, rm

I added my files to local respository, committed the add then removed the files.
I wasn't logged into gitlab at the time. how can I revert it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: Please read [ask] and show your research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the git reflog and checkout the last commit where your files exists and commit it again.

```
git reflog
    
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```